# Child of Nested Flexboxes won't set as scrollable container

Tags: html, css, scroll, flexbox

To prevent text overflow, I want to make the child (.content2) of a flex container (.container2) scrollable. The flex container (.container2) is, in turn, child of another flex container (.container). Due to the nested flexboxes, the height of .content2 can only be set as a fixed value to enable scroll.

How can I handle this issue and get the .content2 container scrollable while taking the remaining space of its parent?

**HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <nav class="navbar">
        <h1>
          Navbar 1
        </h1>
      </nav>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="container2">
          <nav class="navbar2">
            <h1>
              Navbar 2
            </h1>
          </nav>
          <div class="content2">
            <h1>
              This is a static template, there is no bundler or bundling
              involved!
            </h1>
            <h1>
              This is a static template, there is no bundler or bundling
              involved!
            </h1>
            <h1>
              This is a static template, there is no bundler or bundling
              involved!
            </h1>
            <!-- .... and so on, till the text overflows -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Parent Container */

.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
  gap: 10px;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: wheat;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1;
}

/* Child Container */

.container2 {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
  gap: 10px;
}

.navbar2 {
  background-color: wheat;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.content2 {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid purple;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.content2 h1 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

Check this sandbox for your convenience:
[CodeSandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-jones-4hf6ww?file=/index.html:638-10129)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was an one line solution, but took me a while.

```css
.content2 {
  flex: 1 1 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps provide an explanation for why this works. That would be useful.